# Passing column name to the function as variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am relatively new to R and dplyr library. How can I get the function to use the name of the mutated columns as the argument pass in the function?

For example, I want "test" as the name of the mutated column but I get "y". What am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
 library(dplyr)
    d <- data.frame(alpha=1:3, beta=4:6)
    d
    compare_status<-function(x,y){
      x %>% mutate(y=ifelse(alpha ==2,"G2","0"))
    }

    compare_status(d,test)
```

Comment: We were just discussing this yesterday. R is strict about not evaluating the name of the object. There is a new dplyr coming out soon that claims to be able to solve this. If you would like, download the devel version to test it all out. And read through this tutorial http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Is it only for functions that "mutate"?

Comment: No it is strict across all parts of naming positions as far as I have seen.

Comment: Presumably the restriction is there so that a user can write `c(x=1)` rather than `c("x"=1)`. At this point, even if the R gods saw fit to evaluate the left-hand side, they couldn't because so much code written in the past is depending on the value entered being the value shown. Too late to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the devel version `dplyr` syntax for this (soon to be released `0.6.0`)

```
compare_status<-function(x,y){
   y <- quo_name(enquo(y))
    x %>%
      mutate(!!y := ifelse(alpha ==2,"G2","0"))
}

compare_status(d,test)
#  alpha beta test
#1     1    4    0
#2     2    5   G2
#3     3    6    0
```

The `enquo` take the input arguments and convert to `quosure`, which is then converted to strings with `quo_name` and unquoted with `!!` or `UQ` for evaluation as column name on the lhs of assign (`:=`)